# Java 8: Accessibility of Interface members

Tags: java, java-8, jls

**Accessibility**

[Java 8 Says:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

> All members of interfaces ***lacking access modifiers*** are implicitly public

[Java 7 says:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

> **<strike>All members of interfaces are implicitly public.</strike>**

When I tried following code:

```
public interface Test {
    protected int i = 10;
}
```

And compiled, I got

```
Test.java:3: error: modifier protected not allowed here
        protected int i = 10;
                      ^
```

**Java Version:** `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b129)`

But in above `Interface` member declaration I am ***not lacking access modifier*** then why I am getting this error.

Comment: Access specifiers are only allowed for methods I guess, since Java 8 supports default method implementation in iterface.

Comment: @Puru-- I tried `protected void testMethod();` but got compilation error. `Illegal modifier for the interface method test; only public & abstract are permitted`

Comment: and specification says `All members of interfaces lacking access modifiers are implicitly public` not just method

Comment: Yes statement does not say, specific access modifier, you can consider `default` as a access modifier I guess. But you are right you will not be able to use anything other than `public` and `default`

Comment: Just because they added "lacking access modifiers" in Java 8 doesn't mean that they now allow all kinds of access modifiers.  The rules had to be rewritten to support `static` methods and `default` methods.  But other than that, the rules really haven't changed, I think.

Comment: I recall some discussion on the lambda-dev mailing list about allowing protected methods in interfaces now that they have default methods. They may be preparing for adding that in Java 9.

Comment: @DavidConrad But what will be the use of allowing protected methods in Interface.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the idea is that you could have a public template method, and a protected method that helps it get its work done with a default implementation, and classes implementing the interface could override that default, but it wouldn't be visible to outsiders. Outsiders could only call the template method.

Comment: I may not have been remembering correctly after all. I found these two threads that mention protected in interfaces: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-July/005254.html and http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-August/005473.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're quoting is in the JLS section on [Determining Accessibility with Names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)

> All members of interfaces lacking access modifiers are implicitly public

What you really need to be looking at is the section on [interface field declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3) which states

```
ConstantDeclaration:
    {ConstantModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorList ;
ConstantModifier:
    Annotation public 
    static final
```

and

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   `public`, `static`, and `final`. It is permitted to redundantly specify any
>   or all of these modifiers for such fields.

So those are the modifiers you can use. The section you quoted above refers to when you don't use any access modifier, in which case it would be implicitly `public`.

Comment: Please elaborate what is the meaning of Determining Accessibility with **Names**

Comment: @Vishrant As the JLS states, `Names are used to refer to entities declared in a program.` Therefore, _determining accessibility_ is determining if at a certain point in a program, you can access an entity with its name.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is supposed to mean "what you can see from outside the class". It would not make sense to add non-public variable or method. Therefore, interface does not allow protected variables or methods.

Comment: This was according to jls 7 but jls 8 is saying different

Comment: The rules for implicit modifiers do not change in java 8. Implicit modifiers are used when no other modifiers are specified. All members are always public whether implicit or explicit. Note that interface fields were always implicitly public static. This doesn’t change too.

Answer (score 0):

The following phrases in JLS 8 sections 9.3, 9.4, and 9.5 have not changed from JLS 7:

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final.
>
> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public.
>
> A member type declaration in an interface is implicitly public and static.

I think that covers everything, so it seems like it was unnecessary to add "lacking access modifiers" to 6.6.1, unless they wanted to make it clear that a member with a `public` access modifier is *explicitly* public rather than implicitly public.  (Not that there's any significant difference that I'm aware of.)

In any event, one must be rather careful when reading language specifications.  I can see how someone looking *only* at the change in 6.6.1 could conclude that the intent was to relax the rules.  But that isn't the case.  The fact is that the quoted phrases 9.3, 9.4, and 9.5 still apply, and the wording change in 6.6.1 does not supersede that.  Language specifications have to be written in a formal and mathematical manner, so it's not always correct to look at one small section, or one change in one small section, and draw conclusions from it.  You really have to be aware of what the entire spec says and what other sections of the spec are related to the issue, which can be difficult.